# SwiftUI: How to pass core data objects to views?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

**What I want to do:** pass a reference to a NSManagedObject of a FetchRequest (here from: TestView) to another Child-View (here: LogRectangle).

**What I tried:**
These are basically the *important lines*:

```
List(testObjects, id: \.self) { habit in
    LogRectangle(testObject: testObject)
}
```

And this is the whole code:

```
struct TestView : View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: TestObject.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TestObject.name, ascending: true)]
    ) var testObjects: FetchedResults<TestObject>


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    let testObject = TestObject(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                    habit.name = "TestObject String"
                    do {
                        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        // handle the Core Data error
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Insert example TestObject")
                }
                List(testObjects, id: \.self) { habit in
                    LogRectangle(testObject: testObject)
                }
            }
                .navigationBarTitle("Test")
        }
    }
}

struct LogRectangle : View {
    var habit : TestObject

    var body: some View {
        Text(habit.name)
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.white)        
    }
}
```

Here I get this error on the line with the text in the class LogRectangle.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'LocalizedStringKey'
```

Comment: Try this: `Text(string: habit.name)`

Comment: Have you tried passing a non-optional string into Text? Try `Text(habit.name ?? "")`

Comment: @Koen this doesn't change the error

Comment: What's `TestObject`, can you share the code for that?

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering this error perhaps because the attribute, `name`, is defined as an optional string in the data model.

The `Text` struct does not take an optional value. It has to be an explicit value that is:

- A value conforming to the `StringProtocol`
- A literal string that can be used for loading a localized string

[image: Parameters for Text struct]

Therefore, you will need to make some changes to the model that you are passing to the `LogRectangle`. These change can either be made at the data model level (and then updating the associated `NSManagedObject` class, or you can have a computed property on the model to provide a non-optional value of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck using the testObject indices for the list rather than iterating on the actual objects. Try this:

```
List(testObjects.indices, id: \.self) { index in
     LogRectangle(testObject: testObjects[index])
}
```